# Blocking a file while writing it using FileStream append mode in C#

Tags: c#, filestream

I'm appending data to a file using Filestream buffer, see below:

```
using (FileStream filestream = new FileStream(stringPathFile, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
{                                                   
    filestream .Write(stuff.buffer, 0, stuff.bytesRead);
}
```

As debuging, when writing a larger file, I saw the file being written to the destination by every 4096 bytes, and i was able to move the file to somewhere else.  How do I block file being moved around until i complete writing to the file?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Use  `FileShare.ReadWrite` instead of  `FileShare.None`.

EDIT: after some testing in VB.NET 2010 (I don't have access to C# at the moment), I replicated your problem. What seems to fix the problem is avoid using `using`...

`FileStream filestream = new FileStream(stringPathFile, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)
{

    filestream.Write(stuff.buffer, 0, stuff.bytesRead);
}`

Comment: I think the issue here is that once you go beyond the closing bracket, the filestream object is out of scope. If its out of cope, the file its referring to is closed and becomes unlocked. Open the file and keep it open to prevent the file from being moved away.

Comment: Is the path local or network? I am not having any issues with local files.

Comment: That's right using using is the issue here, i will flush out the filestream in the final. Thanks.